# How to compare two strings equal or not in Robot Framework

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How to compare two strings equal or not in Robot Framework.  For example:

```
${xyz}=    Get Text    xpath=/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/h3
${abc}=    Get Text    xpath=/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/h3
```

These xpath values are getting different strings. So how to compare there strings equal or not?

Is it correct way to storing the values in variable in Robot Framework?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many built-in keywords for comparing things.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is the correct way of storing variables.  Though you can also do it without the equal sign:

```
${xyz}    Get Text    xpath=/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/h3
${abc}    Get Text    xpath=/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/h3
```

Now that you have the two different strings assigned to variables, you can simply do:

```
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${xyz}    ${abc}
```

You can see the documentation for `Should Be Equal As Strings` [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.7.5/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal%20As%20Strings).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `Should Be Equal As Strings` is to use [`Should Be True`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20True) - it evaluates the provided argument as python expression (e.g. "something that can be substituted with a value") and fails if it turns up `False`:

```
Should Be True     """${variable 1}""" == """${variable 1}"""
```

It's a good practice to use [triple quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) when you don't have control over the values (e.g. when taken from external source - a web page) - this construct permits the value to have quotes or newlines in it, without causing syntax error.

Though this approach can be a bit cumbersome for simple checks, it is quite powerful - you can use whatever python provides. For example, if the check should be case insensitive:

```
Should Be True     """${variable 1}""".lower() == """${variable 1}""".lower()
```

Or if any starting/trailing whitespace is insignificant:

```
Should Be True     """${variable 1}""".strip() == """${variable 1}""".strip()
```

Or, is one string a part of another:

```
Should Be True     """${variable 1}""" in """${variable 1}"""
```